# 433MHz RFM69 radio joystick controller for drone in Minnesota

Tags: microcontroller, rf, 433mhz

I live in Minnesota. I have an [Adafruit RFM69 433MHz transmitter and receiver.](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3230)

I'm building a quadcopter drone and wondering if I'm allowed as a hobbyist to send continuous data to my drone (such as joystick axis information) over 433.0 MHz legally. Who could I email/call contact directly for a straight answer?

Comment: How continuous you mean by continuous? A packet of few bytes every second, or really continuous stream of data? Don't the ISM band have certain power and duty limits?

Comment: I'd say maybe a few bytes every 100ms.

Comment: no, you have a 5-second limit. I doubt you'll get busted though... 
 https://www.edn.com/using-433-mhz-for-wireless-connectivity-in-the-internet-of-things/ you might want to look into ESP-NOW on the ESP line of cheap MCUs, which uses wifi hardware but isn't wifi but is legal.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: @AlexFish I have planned to do the same thing, I have developped a motherboard with an ATMEGA328PB and a RFM69HCW. I don't know what are your objectives but maybe we could help each other. https://github.com/ARMaudV86/RFMdLib Sources are here if you want to check.
It's still work in progress tho..

Answer (score 0):

433MHz isn't a license-free band in USA - devices using that band for continuous transmission need to reduce output power to some <1mW which probably won't work in your case. You should be using the part "RFM69 @ 900 MHz" designed for the 915MHz band, read the link you posted yourself.

Also no matter band, you need a [FCC](https://www.fcc.gov/) approved radio. If this board has FCC Part 15 approval then you are ready to go. If not, you can't use it.